# IF statesments being ignored in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I new to iOS but I know enough to be dangerous. That said I'm at my wits end and I'm looking for some guidance. I'm dealing with a raft of design issues using iOS but I have found one way to display content the way that I want using a webView and calling in the an HTML page which provides me the desired look and feel.

However I need to have it dynamically call different .html files depending on what the user taps. What I have discovered is that my if conditions are being completely ignored when I step through the code it skips. Below is the code. I have tried this for viewDidAppear as well. Same results. Title is an NSString...so in theory I'm comparing a string with a string.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    if (Title == @"Acme") {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"index"  ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
        [webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];

    } else if (Title == @"NotAcme"{
         NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Page2"  ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webView loadRequest:request];
        [webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
    }


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare `NSString` instances; use `isEqualToString:` instead:

```
if ([Title isEqualToString:@"Acme"]) {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"index"  ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];

} else if ([Title isEqualToString:@"NotAcme"]) {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Page2"  ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
}
```

Comment: OMG I tried that! Didn't work but now it did! WT?!! Carlos Legend! Thanks bud! --- Update: Just worked out that I had missed the [] brackets..der...